# C# Equivalent to ifstream/ofstream in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, ifstream, ofstream

I know this has probably been asked before, but I can't find it here on SO anywhere, and I can't get a clear answer on anything I look up on Google either.

I need to know the C# equivalent to C++'s ifstream/ofstream.

For instance, if I had the following C++ code:

```
ifstream input("myFile.txt");
ofstream output;
output.open("out.txt");
```

What would be the C# equivalent?

I found a site that said (for the in file portion, anyway) that the equivalent was this:

```
using System.IO;

FileStream fs = new FileStream("data.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

I tried putting this in:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(input, FileAccess.Read);
```

I don't have the "FileMode" in mine because VS didn't recognize it.  And "input" is a string in the parameters that holds the string value of the input file name (for example - "myFile.txt").

I know I've got to be missing something silly and minor, but I can't figure out what that is.  Any help on this would be much appreciated!

I'm developing in VS2010, C#-4.0, WPF API.

Comment: MSDN is your friend: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx . Also have a look at the File class shortcuts: Open, OpenText, OpenOrCreate, etc. And if you want something that looks like RAII, there's the using statement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes - Thank you so much for this link! I feel like a complete failure, though.  All it took was to include the "System.IO.FileStream" Library, whereas I only included the "System.IO" Library.  Silly rookie mistakes..

Answer (score 4):

`FileStream` is what you want.  Take a look at the MSDN example on stream composition [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4y2dch9.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your response, although @Martinho Fernandes already gave me what I needed.  I wish I could mark multiple answers as accepted (further, I wish I could mark comments as accepted answers), but thank you for your response nonetheless!

Comment: No problem, glad you got what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that StreamReader/StreamWriter offer similar functionality to c++'s ifstream/ofstream.  FileStream is for dealing with byte[] data, whereas StreamReader/StreamWriter deal with text.

```
var writer = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("myFile.txt");
writer.WriteLine("testing");
writer.Close();
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("myFile.txt");
while ( !reader.EndOfStream )
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
}
```